# How do I convert a PNG to a VTF (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding

I am trying to convert a PNG file that is 512x512 pixels into a VTF file in code.

I've tried looking at the source code for VTFEdit, however, I couldn't understand that much of the code, and most of it is written in C++, which is a language that I have never used before.

Comment: What is a VTF file?

Comment: Are you talking about [Valve Texture Format](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Valve_Texture_Format)? It seems that Valve has documented the file format on that page, so I think it has all the information you need?

Comment: If you're talking about Valve Texture Format, there's no built-in functionality to deal with this file format in the .NET Base Class Library. Third-party libraries usable from C# might or might not exist.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama If there is a documentation, could you send it in the comments. I'll check if there is a library to convert a PNG to a Valve Texture File tomorrow.

Comment: Scroll down on [this page](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Valve_Texture_Format)

Comment: @Heinzi A VTF file is a Valve Texture File. It's used in Half-Life and GMod, I'm sure that there's more games that use VTF files.

Answer (score -1):

**First of all, you need to [convert your PNG to a TGA](https://blog.aspose.com/imaging/convert-png-jpg-to-tga-manipulaute-csharp/) (Truevision Graphics Adapter). This [TGA](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/TGA) can be converted [with this C# lib](https://github.com/guibranco/VTEX-SDK-dotnet) or [this 3rd party program](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/VTFEdit) to a [VTF](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Valve_Texture_Format).**

**Convert PNG or JPG to Truevision TGA Images – API Installation**

> You can easily and efficiently convert a PNG or JPG image to a
> Truevision TGA image in your .NET applications programmatically using
> C#. The conversion can be performed with few API calls once the API is
> configured successfully. You can download Aspose.Imaging for .NET API
> from New Releases or install it via NuGet with the following command:
>
> `Install-Package Aspose.Imaging -Version 20.9.0`
>
> After configuring the API, let us proceed to convert PNG and JPG
> images to TGA image file format.

**Convert PNG Image to Truevison TGA using C#**

> The API supports converting PNG image to Truevision TGA images with
> high fidelity. You can export or render PNG to TGA with the following
> simple steps:
>
> Load input PNG image using RasterImage class object Pass the reference
> of the loaded image to TgaImage instance Save output image with TGA
> file extension The code snippet below shows how to convert PNG image
> to TGA using C#:

```
using (RasterImage image = (RasterImage)Image.Load("test.png"))
{
    using (TgaImage tgaImage = new TgaImage(image))
    {
        tgaImage.Save("test.tga");
    }
}
```

**Now you need to convert this TGA into VTF. You can use this [C# VTEX Lib](https://github.com/guibranco/VTEX-SDK-dotnet) on GitHub or use [this 3rd party program](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/VTFEdit) by Ryan**

Comment: I am asking for the way on how to create the VTF file. Is there anyway to convert the TGA to the VTF in code, saying that I need to convert this TGA into a VTF is quite vague.

Comment: When you say you want to do it "in code", I assume you want to do it using C# in your application. For this, I've hyperlinked you to the appropriate C# library at the beginning and end of my answer above. If this solution does not work for you, then I apologize, but then your intentions are not quite clear to me.

Comment: I'm asking 'How do I convert the TGA to a VTF?'. Is there a function to convert the TGA to a VTF? I've added the library yet I can't find an appropriate function to convert a TGA to a VTF.

Comment: @NotADisplay that's because Thomas added the library without actually knowing what it is. VTEX is a PaaS and has nothing to do with VTF but shares the name with the commandline tool that does it and they assumed. I'm not aware of a package that can do it, and instead you need to run vtex.exe which you can find in the `bin` directory of whichever Source game you have for instance `common/Team Fortress 2/bin`. Then look at the Valve wiki: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Vtex_CLI_use. Or use vtex2: https://github.com/StrataSource/vtex2

Comment: Also Aspose.Imaging is absolute trash as it adds a watermark on the image